# What is the best approach to bind extended interfaces into components based on its type?

Tags: angular, inheritance

I'm migrating an old AngularJs app to Angular 12, and am having some problems coming up with a good approach to solve a problem with inheritance.

It's basically an editor to build a user interface, with custom components such as form, group, row, etc.

Each component has an @Input of its own type, for example, group takes a "group" type.
 `<app-group [elem]=elem> </app-group>`, where elem in this case is of type *Group*. All of these types extend the type `ElemBase`.

All of the elements of various types are stored in a single elements array, of type ElemBase. My goal is to write something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of elems">
    <app-group *ngIf="elem is Group" [elem]="elem"></app-group>
    <app-row *ngIf="elem is Row" [elem]="elem"></app-row>
    <app-button *ngIf="elem is Button" [elem]="elem"></app-button>
</div>
```

Do you lovely people of SO have any recommendations on how to achieve this?
I have tried using a union type such as elements: Array<Group | Row | Button...>, which does not work when binding into each subcomponent.

Thanks in advance,
Have a nice day!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking since there aren't any code of your models etc. but wouldn't it be easier to define a common interface or type that each different type of elements can extend from? Some more code or more clear specifications would be great! :)

Comment: if you are sure sure of your typings, you can use [$any()](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function) to avoid the typing error, even if it s not recommended